# User Defined Function to get longest word in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I've trying to create a UDF in SQL to return the longest word in a string. I've created the following but I cant get it to work properly. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Longestword] (@input varchar(255))

RETURNS varchar(100) 
AS
BEGIN 

    declare @pos int
    declare @pos2 int
    declare @wordpos int
    declare @longestword varchar(100)
    declare @Letter1 varchar (1)
    declare @Letter2 varchar (1)
    declare @twords table (
                            words varchar(100))

    SET @pos = 1
    WHILE @pos <= len(@input) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Letter1 = substring(@input, @pos, 1)
        IF @Letter1 = ' '
        BEGIN
            SET @pos2 = @pos
            WHILE @pos2 <= len(@input)
            BEGIN
                SET @Letter2 = substring(@input, @pos2, 1)
                if @letter2 = ' '
                    BEGIN 
                        insert into @twords
                        select SUBSTRING(@input, @pos,@pos2 - @pos)
                    END
            SET @pos2 = @pos2 + 1
            END

        END
        SET @pos = @pos + 1
    END

    SET @longestword = (select top 1 words from @twords 
                        ORDER BY len(words)desc)

    delete from @twords

RETURN @longestword
END
```

I#m trying to get the different between the 2 spaces and insert that word into a temp table but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use this.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(5000)='aaaa bbbbb cccccccc'

SELECT TOP 1 Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') as longest_Word
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@str, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
ORDER  BY Len(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) DESC
```

**Result** : `cccccccc`

Answer (score -1):

**i found this as solution :** 
[click Here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/udf-for-longest-word-in-string.2921423/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_ex06(@str varchar(8000) )

RETURNS @T TABLE

( position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
value varchar(8000) ,
length smallint null
)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @i int
SET @i = -1
WHILE (LEN(@str) > 0)
BEGIN
SET @i = CHARINDEX(' ' , @str) /* here i used space as delimiter*/
IF (@i = 0) AND (LEN(@str) > 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @T (value, length) VALUES (@str, LEN(@str))
BREAK
END
IF (@i > 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @T (value, length) VALUES (LEFT(@str, @i - 1),
LEN(LEFT(@str, @i - 1)))
SET @str = RIGHT(@str, (LEN(@str) - @i))
END
ELSE
SET @str = RIGHT(@str, (LEN(@str) - @i))
END
RETURN 

END
```

to run this  function you treat it as table because return is a table

```
  select max(value) from  FN_ex06('karim pentester')
```

**result is** : pentester

of course you select all other columns in return table

Comment: You should add more details to the answer rather than just a link because it may be unavailable later.