# How would I get the longest word in a table column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I get longest ***word*** in a string/sentence stored in a given in any row of column of given a table in SQL?

Should return single result row with the length of the word and what the word is.

Motivation: need to know longest search term for search optimization on a highly static data source

Comment: select col from table order by length(col) desc;

Comment: I think @Ankit means `LEN(col)` as we're referring to SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @BJones sorry I wrote oracle syntax.

Comment: @Ankit he wants to know the longest *word* within a column value, *not* the longest column value (the column stores sentences, not words)

Comment: @Bohemian in that case my suggestion is completely wrong. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the answer I neeeded using this, simply change [SomeCodeTable] and do any necessary modifications to the Punctuation to Whitespace replacement line

```
With Strings as (Select [Description] as String From [SomeCodeTable]),,
 Filtered as (Select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(String, '&', ' '), '<', ' '), '>', ' '), '--', ' '), '(', ' '), ')', ' '), ';', ' '), ',', ' '), '/', ' '), '-', ' '), '.', ' ') as String From Strings),
 XmlWords as (Select Cast ('<M>' + Replace(String, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data from Filtered)
SELECT TOP 1 LEN(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) as LongestWordLength, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Word
FROM   XmlWords AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
ORDER  BY Len(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) DESC
```

Code from this previous SO answer was helpful in writing this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876781

Answer (score 0):

You can add a persisted computed column to your table which uses the LEN-Function to store the Length of the desired column. 
When you then put an index on the computed column the

```
 SELECT MAX(<computedcolumn_name>) AS maxLength FROM yourTable
```

will be very efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't it be:  `SELECT MAX(LEN(computedColumn)) AS maxLength FROM yourTable` ?

Comment: No because the computed column already contains the result from the LEN-Function

Comment: ^Oh...okay...missed that part.

Comment: This does not solve the problem stated this merely gives the length of the longest string not the word.

Comment: Sorry the reverse the words in the above comment: meant to say looking for the longest word in the string not the longest string